# Проблема с Javac на Windows 10 при установке Java 8

Tags: java, windows-10

Хочу поставить Java 8 на Windows 10!

Скачал нужный JDK с официального сайта,
создал нужные переменные среды :

```
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\java\jdk8
Path - %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Теперь в командной строке ввожу javac и получаю вот это:

> This version of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin\javac.exe is not compatible     with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system     information and then contact the software publisher.

Что не так?

Comment: Yes, Java was certified on Windows 10 starting with Java 8 Update 51.

Comment: set path="%path%;C:\Program Files\java\jdk8\bin"

Comment: Роборевьюеры закрыли совершенно нормальный вопрос.

Comment: Если предложенный ответ вас устроил, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка справа от текста). Если нет — задавайте уточняющие вопросы в комментариях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была бага на эту тему ([JDK-8066504](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066504)). Судя по бэкпортам должны были исправить в 8u60. Убедитесь, что у вас версия JDK 8u60. На всякий случай — качать [отсюда](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: Да у меня JDK 8u60 версия

Comment: @tarasula, добавьте в вопрос результаты вывода `java -version` и `javac -version`.

Comment: @tarasula, таки заработало что ли?

Comment: Да :) Пришлось скачать еще раз.